# article review as a writing sample for PhD admission

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am asked to submit a writing sample, which could be an article review, a research project, a thesis paper, or a capstone project.

Which one should I submit?

I have review and research papers but all of my papers **have 5 or more authors** in them. So, should I submit a **review or research article** as a writing sample with 5 or more authors in it?

I do not have any capstone project or thesis paper.

Badly in need of some suggestions. Thanks...

Comment: It is a bit unclear. Is the review article a sole-author work?

Comment: no, i am from biomedical background, here working as a sole author is not possible , specially for a undergrade student

Comment: I can't answer for your field, but one of your current professors could probably give good advice on this. Especially someone younger who had to deal with the same issue not so long ago.

Comment: Are you sure that they do not intend that you should pick up an article and resume it? I mean is an article review or a review article? Before PhD, usually one can submit his/her thesis and not much more...

Answer (score 2):

If I were reading a writing sample as part of an application I would be skeptical of anything with multiple authors. If you have only such samples you should make clear that you were the principal writer (not necessarily even a main contributor)  if that was the case. If not, then I think you should find some other document to submit, even if it was not formally published. An undergraduate term paper might serve, along with an explanation about why you chose to submit that particular piece.

Comment: @Buffy Of course. You could have fixed it.

Comment: Yes, but then my moniker gets attached on the listing page. Better that it is associated with yourself.